# Elastic BeanStalk Failing when deployed with NextAuth

Tags: node.js, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next-auth

When deployed Next App with Next Auth on AWS Beanstalk, but faced with the error below when accessing the app. Was wondering if anyone had similar issues or share any insights as couldn't find any info about this on their github repo or documentation FAQ. I have posted an issue on their Github Repo too.

```
Jan 26 09:44:11 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > galleri-client@0.1.0 start
Jan 26 09:44:11 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > next build && next start -p $PORT
Jan 26 09:44:12 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Creating an optimized production build ...
Jan 26 09:44:16 ip-10-0-0-140 web: âœ“ Compiled successfully
Jan 26 09:44:16 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Linting and checking validity of types ...
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Collecting page data ...
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at 4570 (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:1127)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_exec__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2659)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2694
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__.X (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1610)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2672
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2736)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > Build error occurred
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: type: 'Error'
Jan 26 09:44:20 ip-10-0-0-140 web: }
```

Using the latest version, Below is what i have on my .....[nextauth]/route.ts
Dont worry about the well-known config url

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. 'Sign in with...')
      name: "Credentials",
      // The credentials is used to generate a suitable form on the sign in page.
      // You can specify whatever fields you are expecting to be submitted.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials || !credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }
        const user = users.find((item) => item.email === credentials.email);
        if (user?.password === credentials.password) {
          return user;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
    {
      id: "CIS2",
      name: "CIS2",
      type: "oauth",
      version: "2.0",
      clientId: process.env.CIS2_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CIS2_SECRET,
      wellKnown:
        "https://......./openam/oauth2/realms/root/realms/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "openid email profile nationalrbacaccess",
          redirect_uri: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
        },
      },
      idToken: true,
      checks: ["state"],
      profile(profile) {
        return (
          // console.log("profile", profile),
          {
            id: profile.sub,
            name: profile.name,
            email: profile.email,
            image: profile.picture,
          }
        );
      },
    },
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    // Choose how you want to save the user session.
    // The default is `"jwt"`, an encrypted JWT (JWE) stored in the session cookie.
    // If you use an `adapter` however, we default it to `"database"` instead.
    // You can still force a JWT session by explicitly defining `"jwt"`.
    // When using `"database"`, the session cookie will only contain a `sessionToken` value,
    // which is used to look up the session in the database.
    // strategy: "database",

    // Seconds - How long until an idle session expires and is no longer valid.
    maxAge: 60 * 15, // 15 min

    // Seconds - Throttle how frequently to write to database to extend a session.
    // Use it to limit write operations. Set to 0 to always update the database.
    // Note: This option is ignored if using JSON Web Tokens
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // console.log("session callback", { session, token });
      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The pipeline builds fine but when try accessing the app there is an nginx errror, and checking the logs found this

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Jan 26 11:51:42 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Jan 26 11:51:42 ip-10-0-0-140 web: type: 'Error'
Jan 26 11:51:42 ip-10-0-0-140 web: }
Jan 26 11:51:43 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > galleri-client@0.1.0 start
Jan 26 11:51:43 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > next build && next start -p $PORT
Jan 26 11:51:44 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Creating an optimized production build ...
Jan 26 11:51:48 ip-10-0-0-140 web: âœ“ Compiled successfully
Jan 26 11:51:48 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Linting and checking validity of types ...
Jan 26 11:51:52 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Collecting page data ...
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at 4570 (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:1127)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_exec__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2659)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2694
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__.X (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1610)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2672
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2736)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > Build error occurred
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: type: 'Error'
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: }
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > galleri-client@0.1.0 start
Jan 26 11:51:53 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > next build && next start -p $PORT
Jan 26 11:51:54 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Creating an optimized production build ...
Jan 26 11:51:59 ip-10-0-0-140 web: âœ“ Compiled successfully
Jan 26 11:51:59 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Linting and checking validity of types ...
Jan 26 11:52:03 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Collecting page data ...
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at 4570 (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:1127)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_exec__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2659)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2694
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__.X (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1610)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2672
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2736)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > Build error occurred
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: type: 'Error'
Jan 26 11:52:04 ip-10-0-0-140 web: }
Jan 26 11:52:05 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > galleri-client@0.1.0 start
Jan 26 11:52:05 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > next build && next start -p $PORT
Jan 26 11:52:06 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Creating an optimized production build ...
Jan 26 11:52:10 ip-10-0-0-140 web: âœ“ Compiled successfully
Jan 26 11:52:10 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Linting and checking validity of types ...
Jan 26 11:52:14 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Collecting page data ...
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at 4570 (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:1127)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_exec__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2659)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2694
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__.X (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1610)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2672
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2736)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > Build error occurred
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: type: 'Error'
Jan 26 11:52:15 ip-10-0-0-140 web: }
Jan 26 11:52:16 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > galleri-client@0.1.0 start
Jan 26 11:52:16 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > next build && next start -p $PORT
Jan 26 11:52:17 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Creating an optimized production build ...
Jan 26 11:52:21 ip-10-0-0-140 web: âœ“ Compiled successfully
Jan 26 11:52:21 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Linting and checking validity of types ...
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Collecting page data ...
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at 4570 (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:1127)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_exec__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2659)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2694
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at __webpack_require__.X (/var/app/current/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1610)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2672
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:1:2736)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > Build error occurred
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: type: 'Error'
Jan 26 11:52:25 ip-10-0-0-140 web: }
Jan 26 11:52:26 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > galleri-client@0.1.0 start
Jan 26 11:52:26 ip-10-0-0-140 web: > next build && next start -p $PORT
Jan 26 11:52:27 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Creating an optimized production build ...
Jan 26 11:52:32 ip-10-0-0-140 web: âœ“ Compiled successfully
Jan 26 11:52:32 ip-10-0-0-140 web: Linting and checking validity of types ...
```